# Are there any airline companies in Europe that make discounts if you buy flights in batch?

Tags: air-travel, budget

I recently saw that Ryanair does a [15% discount for 8 flights](https://www.ryanair.com/gb/en/plan-trip/explore/erasmus) for Erasmus students.
I was wondering if these promotions exist in either Ryanair or other companies to clients if they guarantee to buy a certain amount of flights.

I am aware that several companies sell fixed rate flights if you buy a batch in advance like [KLM](https://klmflightbundle.klm.com/Worldwide_Sites.do?processAction=paramLnk&p=/01KLFPO1/)  or [TAP](https://www.flytap.com/en-pt/flight-pass) allowing you to book later. Prices however are not that good. The only thing you get is mostly predictability in fares and not discounts on published price for a given day. You will be able to do things like buy a day in advance and know that you will get the same fixed price.

This predictability might be instersting for companies or other users but I am looking for something more like Ryanair does. Discounts on published fares if you guarantee to buy a certain amount of flights.

**Are there any airline companies in Europe that make discounts if you buy flights in batch?**

Answer (score 3):

I just read about this on Air France this past week. See this page from the Points Guy for more details: [Air France Le Pass](https://thepointsguy.com/news/air-frances-le-pass-lets-you-buy-up-to-900-flights-at-once/) (Note: I am in no way associated with TPG).

What it looks like is that you can buy "Le Pass" for a given number of flights with a given amount of specificity on routes and timings. You can choose a specific route, or choose flights between, say, France and Germany (long-haul flights are not available). The price depends both on the number of flights you buy and on how specific you are.

They advertise up to a 70% discount, but you'd have to play around with it to see what you can actually find.

Answer (score 1):

The term you're probably looking for is "group booking" or "group travel".  Examples for [KLM](https://www.klm.com/travel/it_en/plan_and_book/booking/groups/index.htm), [TAP](https://www.flytap.com/en-us/booking-information/group-travel), and [Ryanair](https://www.ryanair.com/us/en/plan-trip/flying-with-us/groups).

In general I wouldn't expect to see much, if any of a discount from these offers, and there will be some additional friction in booking them.  I think these plans are meant more for synchronizing tour groups and such, rather than as a bulk discount.  Also note that it might be difficult to compare pricing for a group of 12 by just looking at the lowest available price and multiplying by 12, since any particular flight may not actually have 12 seats available at the lowest price.

Comment: I think they mean "bulk" as in one person flying 12 times rather than 12 people flying once...

Comment: Exactly. That's what I meant.